# Vagrant - The following settings shouldn't exist: memory, name

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I have moved this question over from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/825518/vagrant-the-following-settings-shouldnt-exist-memory-name) I thought it was more of a question belonging there :-)

I have Vagrant version 1.9.1 on macOS and I have VirtualBox 5.1.12
I am trying to have a go at creating a multi machine Vagrant file and I am running into trouble when I want to run it.

I get the message:

> There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
>   the following errors and try again:
>
> vm:
>   * The following settings shouldn't exist: memory, name

Now at this stage I have commented out the second machine, because I get the error twice - so I am just trying to fix the first one.

I have seen on other threads I should remove the `.vm` in the lines that are in the "web" block, but if I do that then I get this error:

> There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
>   the following errors and try again:
>
> Vagrant:
>   * Unknown configuration section 'memory='.
>   * Unknown configuration section 'name='.
>   * Unknown configuration section 'network'.
>   * Unknown configuration section 'provision'.

I am at a bit of a loss here, because the answers I am getting make sense in theory and I started this from the vagrant up docs, but somehow in my case I can't get it running.

My vagrant file is right here - so please any help would be appreciated :-)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
end

config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.name = "16.04-web01"
    web.vm.memory = "512"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3"
    web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8083
    web.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
    web.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"    
end

#    config.vm.define :sql01 do |sql|
#     sql.vm.name = "16.04-sqlserver"
#     sql.vm.memory = "4096"
#     sql.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2"
#     sql.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8084
#     sql.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
#     sql.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"    
#   end

#Options for Me specific
config.vm.synced_folder "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/", "/htdocs_home"

end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`name` and `memory` are provider specific parameters so they need to be moved in this block

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu1604"

    config.vm.define "web" do |web|
        web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3"
        web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8083
        web.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
        web.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"    

        web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.gui = false
            vb.name = "16.04-web01"
            vb.memory = "512"
        end
    end

    config.vm.define :sql01 do |sql|
        sql.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2"
        sql.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8084
        sql.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
        sql.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"    

        sql.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.gui = false
            vb.name = "16.04-sqlserver"
            vb.memory = "4096"
        end
    end

    #Options for Me specific
    config.vm.synced_folder "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/", "/htdocs_home"

end
```

Comment: So can I set a different name and memory allocation to different machines?

Comment: sure .. editing the answer to show the example ... the provider block then needs to be within each VM block, if you set outside it applies for all VM

Comment: Ah thats cool that makes sense - didn't think about putting the provider inside the definitions :-)

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot with my scriptis